# Как задать текст span как value для input?

Tags: javascript

Как задать текст span как value для input?

```html
<input class="input-example">
<span class="span-example">Текст</span>
```

Comment: Что Вы уже пробовали, и что не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let span = document.querySelector('.span-example');
let input = document.querySelector('.input-example');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) =>{
  span.textContent = input.value;
})
```

```html
<input class="input-example">
<span class="span-example">Текст</span>
```